# how to use code igniter for iframes

Tags: javascript, html, codeigniter, iframe

does code igniter provide css or javascript to help make iframes and web pages within webpages? Any suggestions on how to go about doing this in CI?  I need to make a menu that when you put your mouse over it, the button while drop down other buttons. The when you click the corresponding button the iframe below populates from the database.

Comment: This really has nothing to do with codigniter, This is a HTML / Javascript Frontend issue...

Answer (score 0):

No, CodeIgniter does not provide any help on Javascript manipulation. It is a PHP framework. Server based, not oriented toward client interfaces.

**EDIT :**
Since, this has been downvoted, let me quote official CodeIgniter documentation.

> **Javascript Class** :  Note: This driver is **experimental**. Its
>   feature set and implementation may change in future releases.

With link provided : [documentation](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/javascript.html).

Plus, I have downloaded the latest version 2.0.2. It does not contain any css nor javascript files. (Except for their documentation).